# Rest Api Filter on Number Field Starts with

Tags: rest, api

On SharePoint 2013 On Premise, I need rest api filter where I can search some numbers in list starts with. Since records are around 100,000 I can not display all. Hence need a kind of search function.

Comment: Do you need to filter on single column values...is that right?

Comment: yes. There is only one number field. I want to search number 123xxx

Comment: I have added the example in answer section for Title field. similarly you can do for your field. if useful, please up vote. :)

Comment: You can use `startswith` on String and not the number. Refer this link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#bk_supported

Comment: The work around is you can combine `Ge` and `Le` (i.e. greater than equal to and less than equal to) to get the required result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter on column something like given below:

```
var endpointUri = appwebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items?$select=*&$filter=startswith(Title,'value')";
```

Comment: I want it on a number field

Comment: You can use it on number field too.... Just add the internal name of your number field replacing 'Title' and the number you want to search replacing 'value' in above example.

Comment: have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a numberfield or a textfield?

If its a numberfield why not create a filter that compares a number greater than the numberfield?

Something like this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list')/items?$filter=[Numberfield] ge 123000
```

Where ge is Greater than or equal.

Comment: I think Vikas wants to search the number starting with 123xxx. Not the values greater than that 123xxx.

Comment: Yeah but as he writes numberfield and not text field I dont really know what he means. He need to clarify if its a number or a textstring he want to search for.

Comment: I want to search number startswith 123... not greater than

Comment: You cant cast a number value in SharePoints REST api and therefore not use startswith so i think your only valid option is to use my method where you look for number bigger than the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

e.g. To get item with the number `444` in `numberfield`:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('testCRUD')/items?$select=*&$filter=(numberfield ge '444') and (numberfield le '444')
```